# Trying to update my table, instead of 1 row getting updated all rows get the change

Tags: java

As the title states I am trying to edit fields in and existing (local) MySQL server.
Adding and removing rows works like a charm, but when I try to edit them using this code:

```
    private void EditActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     

   try{
       String edit1 = lNaam.getText();
       String edit2 = lEmail.getText();
       String edit3 = lAdres.getText();
       String edit4 = lPlaats.getText();
       String edit5 = lPostcode.getText();
       String edit6 = lTelefoon.getText();
       String edit7 = lBedrijfsNaam.getText();

       String sql="update customers set naam='"+edit1+"',email='"+edit2+"',adres='"+edit3+"',plaats='"+edit4+"',postcode='"+edit5+"',telefoon='"+edit6+"',bedrijfsnaam='"+edit7+"'where KL_NR";
       preparedStatement=connect.prepareStatement(sql);
       preparedStatement.execute();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Updated");

   }catch(SQLException | HeadlessException e){
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
   }
    Update_table();

}
```

**EDIT: I FORGOT TO SAY THIS, THE KL_NR FIELD IS A AUTO_INCREMENT FIELD, WHICH IS SUPPOSED TO STAY THE SAME, I HAVE NO IDEA WHAT TO PUT THERE**

It keeps editing all the rows in the table in stead of just 1.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nQNp.jpg

this code is used to select the rows, for deletion etc.:

```
    private void Table_customerMouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                             
  try{

    int row = Table_customer.getSelectedRow();
    String TClick = (Table_customer.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString());
    String sql="select * from customers where KL_NR='"+TClick+"'";
    preparedStatement=connect.prepareStatement(sql);
    resultSet=preparedStatement.executeQuery();
    if(resultSet.next()){
        String add1 =resultSet.getString("naam");
        lNaam.setText(add1);
        String add2 =resultSet.getString("Email");
        lEmail.setText(add2);
        String add3 =resultSet.getString("Adres");
        lAdres.setText(add3);
        String add4 =resultSet.getString("Plaats");
        lPlaats.setText(add4);
        String add5 =resultSet.getString("Postcode");
        lPostcode.setText(add5);
        String add6 =resultSet.getString("Telefoon");
        lTelefoon.setText(add6);
        String add7 =resultSet.getString("Bedrijfsnaam");
        lBedrijfsNaam.setText(add7);
    }



    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

this is my deletion code:

```
private void DeleteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    String sql ="delete from test.customers where NAAM=? ";
    try {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement(sql);

        preparedStatement.setString(1, lNaam.getText());
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Deleted");

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DataView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    Update_table();
}
```

I hope you can help me. :S

Comment: By what criteria do you determine which row to update?

Comment: your where clause in update statement in flawed

Comment: Please read about SQL injection

Comment: i edited the main question, i forgot to say something about that where clause

Comment: @user2674895: which row do you want to edit?

Comment: @jlordo the row i select with the mouse, i can delete any row I want with that method, but if i try to edit it. it doesnt quite work.

Comment: @user2674895: Then you need `... where KL_NR = KL_NR of selected row` ... the same way you are doing it in your delete method.

Comment: @jlordo i just tried that, it changed all the rows again in stead of the one selected. i also tried this `where naam='"+edit1+"'` which hails the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't provide a condition in your `WHERE`,

```
String sql="update customers set naam='"+edit1+"',email='"+edit2+"',adres='"+edit3+"',plaats='"+edit4+"',postcode='"+edit5+"',telefoon='"+edit6+"',bedrijfsnaam='"+edit7+"'where KL_NR";
```

should end with something like

```
..."+edit7+"'where /* CONDITION HERE TO UPDATE THE WANTED ROW*/;
```

If the condition for the selection works, use the same for the update unless there's other criteria than the selected row to know what to update.

```
int row = Table_customer.getSelectedRow();
String TClick = (Table_customer.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString())
String sql="update customers set naam='"+edit1+"',email='"+edit2+"',adres='"+edit3+"',plaats='"+edit4+"',postcode='"+edit5+"',telefoon='"+edit6+"',bedrijfsnaam='"+edit7+"'where KL_NR='"+TClick+"'";
```

Comment: OH dang sorry forgot to add that bit in the question, the KL_NR is a AUTO_INCREMENT field, a field that doesnt change.

Comment: I totally overlooked the TClick solution you posted, as soon as i read it it registered in my mind as something i had thought up >.< excuse my retardation.

Answer (score 3):

for updating you should call executeUpdate method

```
String sql="update customers set naam='"+edit1+"',email='"+edit2+"',adres='"+edit3+"',plaats='"+edit4+"',postcode='"+edit5+"',telefoon='"+edit6+"',bedrijfsnaam='"+edit7+"'where KL_NR";
       preparedStatement=connect.prepareStatement(sql);
       preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

**And** your sql string is incomplete meaning you have to complete where condition like
update table set Name='test' where ID=5;

**Also** this is not the proper way of using PreparedStatement.

Use this way

```
String sql="update customers set naam=?,email=?....."

preparedStatement=connect.prepareStatement(sql);
preparedStatement.setString(1,edit1);
preparedStatement.setString(2,edit2);
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: i edited the main question, i forgot to say something about that where clause.

Comment: @user2674895 If that field is autoincrement then its an int type so use this way where KL_NR=2 or where KL_NR=3 orwhere KL_NR=4 etc

Comment: I know that, but i can select the row i want(inJtable)(with a mouseclick) and delete that singular row, but if i want to edit it by that method you suggested, it only edits the row stated in the hardcoded SQL command.

Comment: @user2674895 use the same condition as your selection query, check my answer.

Comment: @user2674895 if you want for tclick then in the where clause use tclick

Answer (score 0):

your Update statement must be like this

```
 String sql="update customers set naam='"+edit1+"',email='"+edit2+"',adres='"+edit3+"',plaats='"+edit4+"',postcode='"+edit5+"',telefoon='"+edit6+"',bedrijfsnaam='"+edit7+"'where KL_NR="+/*some value*/;
```